# Connecting to an FPGA from virtualbox

Tags: ssh, virtualbox, fpga

I am trying to be connected to an FPGA from my ubuntu on virtualbox via ssh. But I receive the error that
 ssh: connect to host 192.168.1.5 port 22: Connection timed out
I have no idea what is the source of problem. Do you have any hints?
Thank you very much.

Comment: Are you connecting to a soft processor running inside the FPGA?  FPGAs themselves usually don't have ssh access.

Comment: Yes, It is a Digilent ZYBO board, that has an ethernet socket mounted on it (via CAT6 I have connected it to an ethernet switch) , and an SD which I already programmed.

Comment: You'd probably get a better response at http://superuser.com/ instead

Answer (score 0):

The Zybo board by default runs PetaLinux. You will need to install a SSH server in PetaLinux. OpenSSH is an option.